# Firebase: Re-authenticate user after app reopen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

When I log in to the app with the Apple provider using Firebase and Expo, I can access **auth.currentUser** anywhere in my app. However, when I reopen the app, the **currentUser in auth()** is set to null.". My end goal is to re-authenticate user when app re-open. Like it did on first sign up

Here's my approach:
this is my splash screen code

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        try {
            if (user) {
                this.props.setUser(JSON.parse(user));
            } else {
                this.unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
                    console.log('ON AUTH CHANGED');
                    this.props.setUser(currentUser);
                    if (currentUser) {
                        AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(currentUser));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Clean up the subscription when the component unmounts
        if (this.unsubscribe) {
            this.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
```

Login Provider:

```
function AppleLogin() {
return (
    <Pressable onPress={async () => {
        try {
            const applecCredential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
                requestedScopes: [
                    AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
                    AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL,
                ],
            })
            let { identityToken } = applecCredential
            if (identityToken) {
                let provider = new OAuthProvider('apple.com')
                provider.addScope('email')
                provider.addScope('name')
                const credential = provider.credential({ idToken: identityToken })
                signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
            }

        } catch (e) {
            if (e.code === 'ERR_REQUEST_CANCELED') {
            } else {
            }
        }
    }}>
        <Image style={{ width: normalize(50), height: normalize(50) }} resizeMode="contain" source={require('./assets/login/apple.png')} />
    </Pressable>
);
```

}

Comment: currentUser will be null until the Firebase SDK knows that the user is signed in, and that doesn't happen until after the `onAuthStateChanged` observer lets you know that is the case.  You are accessing currentUser before that observer fires.

Comment: what would you suggest to do? @DougStevenson